# Простая программа bash

Tags: linux, bash

> Выведите таблицу сумм всех натуральных чисел от 1 до m для каждого числа m от 1 до n, где n вводится с клавиатуры.
>   *Подсказка:* предполагается, что вы вспомните формулу суммы членов арифметической
>   прогрессии.

Не понимаю, как это вообще работает, хелп ;D

Comment: Bush младший или старший?

Comment: до первой скобки "(пишем..."  грубый копипаст, хоть бы текст задачи отредактировали, а то Бушу грустно(

Answer (score 1):

```
read n  
n=$(($n + 1))  
sum=0  
for ((m=1; m <n; m++)) do  
sum=$(( $m * ($m+1) / 2 ))  
echo "$m -> $sum "  
done  
echo 'end'
```

Это было слишком просто, надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится)))

Comment: отлично, Буш будет доволен!)

Comment: "надеюсь кому-нибудь пригодится" - конечно не теряйте надежду, но не рабочий код никому не пригодится.

Comment: Нужно было хотя бы сфотографировать экран, а то скриншот текста это несерьёзно

Comment: @andreymal, настоящие парни распечатывают скрин, а потом фотографируют лист.